# Before login hook

Tags: 8, hooks, authentication-authorization

Is there a Drupal 8 hook for pre-login? I would like to redirect the login information of a user on a web server by URL.

I know there is `hook_user_login()`, but this one only looks called once the user is connected to the database. I would like to retrieve the step before, so the login and password information.

Comment: Can you use the hook_user_login hook, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/8.2.x?

Comment: @Jdrupal if I have understood correctly this function only works when the user is connected, I would like the step before. So during the login / password verification

Comment: You mean when the user login form is submitted? Then add a custom validate callback before the core ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by implementing `hook_form_alter`, something like this;

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_user_login_validate';
  }
}

function my_module_user_login_validate(&$form, $form_state) {
  //Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alter for using `hook_form_alter`. Login page form id is `user_login_form` so use that and add your extra validation handler like below :

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_user_login_validate';
  }
}

function my_module_user_login_validate(&$form, $form_state) {
  //Do something...
}
```